# Limit the number of rows returned on the server side (forced limit)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, client-server

So we have a piece of software which has a poorly written SQL statement which is causing every row from a table to be returned.  There are several million rows in the table so this is causing serious memory issues and crashes on our clients machine.  The vendor is in the process of creating a patch for the issue, however it is still a few weeks out.  In the mean time we were attempting to figure out a method of limiting the number of results returned on the server side just as a temporary fix.

I have no real hope of there being a solution, I've looked around and don't really see any ways of doing this, however I'm hoping someone might have an idea.

Thank you in advance.

*EDIT*

I forgot an important piece of information, we have no access to the source code so we can not change this on the client side where the SQL statement is formed.  There is no real server side component, the client just accesses the database directly.  Any solution would basically require a procedure, trigger, or some sort of SQL-Server 2008 setting/command.

Comment: Will that temporary fix break the application however?  Do you know how this data is being used?

Comment: Rename the table and replace it with a view that does a `SELECT TOP x * FROM new_name_of_the_table`. Note, however, that data manipulations (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) performed by the application will fail afterwards.

Comment: @Heinzi Unfortunately we'd need to be able to insert, update, and delete.

Comment: Why is the SQL statement formed in the Client application?  If the SQL is formed in the Client application, and you don't have the source code for this, I can't see how you'll limit the number of rows returned.

Comment: @Ardman hence why I asked the question, I was wondering if there was a setting or method of putting a hard limit on the database end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**One possible solution could be to**

- rename the offending table
- create an [updatable view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258253(SQL.80).aspx) with the original tablename
- do a `SELECT TOP x * FROM OffendingTable` as your view definition

As such, the client isn't aware of the change when selecting the data.

---

**Use the [query governor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190419.aspx)**

If you don't mind returning no data at all for the offending query, the query governor allows you to do so.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, similar to Heinzi's comment, however then insert, update, and delete statements within the application would not work.

Comment: @evolve, it becomes more difficult but you should read up on updatable views. I don't know of hand if it would be possible with your requirements but I believe so.

Comment: This almost worked, inserts/updates/deletes work without an issue, however if you do SELECT top 100 * FROM {table} it always returns the top same top 100, it doesn't base the top 100 off the query being executed.  Sometimes they have WHERE statements within the query which need to work.  So close though.

Comment: @evolve, as there isn't any kind of event where you could "massage" the entire resultset before it is returned to the client, the answer given by Marcus Adams is the only one that could actually work.

Comment: Agreed, thank you for the suggestions though, as this was best possible solution to my question I am marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There got to be a command for it.

I know in MYSQL it is "LIMIT(firstindex,lastindex)" at the end of the sql statement.

I think I heard in MSSQL you can write :

Select TOP 10,20 ... or something like this

That would mean you select 20 rows with 10 beginning i think

Answer (score 1):

you can use select top

SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM Persons(http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

or

Do the paging like this will help you

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetRequestedRecordByPage] 
 @FromList nvarchar(200)              -- Table Name  
,@SortingCol nvarchar(200)         -- Sorting column Name
,@SelectList nvarchar(200) = '*'         -- Select columns list
,@WhereClause nvarchar(200) = ''        -- Where clause i.e condition
,@PageNum int = 1                           -- Requested page number
,@PageSize int = 5                 -- No of record in page
,@TotalNoOfRecord int output         -- Total no of selected records
AS 
Begin
  SET NOCOUNT ON 
  DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)         -- query going to be execute

  IF rtrim(ltrim(@WhereClause)) <> '' 
  BEGIN
      SET @Query ='SELECT   @TotalNoOfRecord = COUNT(*) 
                      FROM     ' + @FromList + ' 
        WHERE    ' + @WhereClause 
  END
  ELSE 
  BEGIN 
      SET @Query ='SELECT   @TotalNoOfRecord = COUNT(*) 
                      FROM     ' + @FromList 
  END

    /* Count no. of record */
       EXEC sp_executeSQL 
        @Query, 
        @params = N'@TotalNoOfRecord INT OUTPUT', 
         = @TotalNoOfRecord OUTPUT 

DECLARE @lbound int, @ubound int 




/* Calculating upper and lower bound */
        SET @lbound = ((@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize) 
        SET @ubound = @lbound + @PageSize + 1 


/* Get list of record(s) */
        SELECT @Query =  ''
        SELECT @Query =  'SELECT  * 
                          FROM    ( 
SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ' + @SortingCol  + ') AS rownumber,' +@SelectList  +   
                                        ' FROM    ' + @FromList 

        IF rtrim(ltrim(@WhereClause)) <> '' 
        BEGIN
            SELECT @Query = @Query + ' WHERE   ' + @WhereClause 
        END

            SELECT @Query = @Query + '     ) AS tbl 
WHERE rownumber > ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @lbound) + 
      ' AND rownumber < ' + CONVERT(varchar(9), @ubound) 

       EXEC (@Query)                 
End
```

Comment: It sounds as though he doesn't have access to the SQL

Answer (score 1):

If the client is using TCP to connect to the database, you can insert a mostly transparent TCP proxy server between the client and database server on the server side. You can then rewrite any offending queries that come from the client (using TOP or some means of improving the query).

You then configure SQL Server to run on a different port, start up your proxy to serve on the original port and have it connect to SQL server on the new port. If you know the client's originating IP address, you could use port forwarding so that you could direct just them to the proxy, and leave the database server configured as is.

I could write and test this in an hour, but it does take some knowledge of socket programming.

Comment: +1. As an ubergeek solution this would be way cool. I doubt it would be doable in an hour but it certainly is doable.

Comment: Cool solution, not plausible though.

Comment: @Evolve, I've used this solution for other types of production systems. Admittedly, I've not used it for a database system, but I would.

Answer (score 0):

You could drop all but X records from the table and store them somewhere else